# Size of the parameter in applet call is too big

Tags: java, javascript, applet, liveconnect

I have problem in passing some data from JavaScript to an applet. I think size of data is too big (18M characters in string) to pass it through LiveConnect.

I put code samples below:

JavaScript:

```
var bigData = generateSomeBigData(18000000); // string contaning 18 000 000 characters
applet.Execute(bigData); // no error
```

Applet:

```
public void Execute(String data) {
    this.doSomethingWithData(data);  // data is null
}
```

I didn't get any error or exceptions in java console or in javascript code.
I've tried running applet with bigger heap, but it didn't help.

```
... <param name="java_arguments" value="-Xmx128m" /> ...
```

The only problem is I get `null` instead of string contaning data, it doesn't depend on browser (FF, Chrome).

Comment: *"Size of the parameter in applet call is too big"*  Yes, of course 18 Megabytes is too big!  ..Do you have a question?

Comment: Yes, how to pass even bigger data to an applet?

Comment: I could implement some fragmentation mechanism, but I'm asking is there a way to allow passing big data with only changed applet configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. I moved data generation to server site and I'm passing data to applet using `one time self destructing link`. Applet can download information, which is no more available, and return result.

Here you have an example:

Server:

```
String bigData = this.generateBigData(18000000);
String linkToData = this.getOneTimeLink(bigData);
```

JavaScript:

```
applet.Execute(linkToBigData);
```

Applet:

```
public void Execute(String link) {
    String data = this.downloadData(link);
    this.doSomethingWithData(data);  // data is not null ;)
}
```

**EDIT 11 May 2015:**

Maybe you need a small explanation to one time destructing link. I used it because it was another requirement to my project but it is not necessary to achieve solution.